# Unknown character "/�" appended automatically

Tags: html, css

Some unknown character is getting appended automatically to `content:'/'` on `before` element. 
[image]

If I remove the � and click outside.. it gets appended automatically ...

[image]

any way to get rid of this..

Comment: Need more information about the dev environment. Where do you edit this code? What CSS preprocessors/minifiers/etc do you use? Also could you tell us the code of these characters?

Comment: What gets appended automatically where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested by manually adding the character to a stylesheet and then attempting to remove it via Developer Console (on [Chrome](https://i.imgur.com/rfedcMj.gifv) and [Opera](https://i.imgur.com/Y0DPWB1.gifv)). Turns out, it comes back by itself when I click out, exactly as it's happening to you.

The only way it didn't come back was when I removed the `/` as well and then wrote it again. My guess is that the browser doesn't recognize that anything has changed when it compares the initial value (`/�`) with the altered value (`/`), probably due to a `.trim()` on the browser's code or something along those lines.

What I can recommend is that you look for that part of the code and rewrite the line (or at least that `"/";` part). That character may be invisible on your code editor and, thus, you're only seeing it on the browser.

---

*Note*: This doesn't seem to happen on [Firefox](https://i.imgur.com/N9NV4pr.gifv), and on [IE / Edge](https://i.imgur.com/LVHQB47.gifv) (although on the latter it won't update until you disable and then reenable the property). Removing the character works just fine and the property is changed.